# c# using a AutoResetEvent appears to block reading from serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

This is a winforms application.

I'm talking to a MCU over USB/serial. When it turns on, it sends a message. I attach a listener to the `DataReceived` event then use an `AutoResetEvent` to signal the GUI thread when to read. When I put in some logging, it appears the listener is only triggered once the call to `WaitOne` has timed out. It appears that the call to `WaitOne` also blocks the `DataReceived` event. Is this correct? How do I get around it?

```
private UartService uart;
private AutoResetEvent latch = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public void open()
{
    uart = new UartService(ComPort);
    uart.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
    uart.open();

    // Wait for the greeting 
    readResponse(1, 5000);
}

public List<string> readResponse(int expectedArraySize, int timeout)
{
    if (!latch.WaitOne(timeout))
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("timed out");
    }

    if (lastResponseBuffer.IndexOf(OK) < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("bad response");
    }

    return lastResponseBuffer;
}

public void MessageReceived(object source, string message)
{
    // Process message
    ...
    lastResponseBuffer.Add(message);


    latch.Set();
}
```

UartService.cs...

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads from and writes to a COM port.
    /// </summary>
    public class UartService
    {
        public const string NEWLINE = "\r\n";

        private string port;
        private int baudRate;
        private Parity parity;
        private int bitsPerWord;
        private StopBits stopBits;
        private SerialPort serialPort;
        private int timeout = 2000;

        public UartService(string port, int baudRate = 115200, Parity parity = Parity.None, 
            int bitsPerWord = 8, StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One)
        {
            this.port = port;
            this.baudRate = baudRate;
            this.parity = parity;
            this.bitsPerWord = bitsPerWord;
            this.stopBits = stopBits;
        }

        public void setTimeout(int timeout)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        public void open()
        {
            serialPort = new SerialPort(port, baudRate, parity, bitsPerWord, stopBits);
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = timeout;
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = timeout;
            serialPort.NewLine = NEWLINE;
            serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceived;
            serialPort.Open();
        }

        public void close()
        {
            serialPort.DataReceived -= DataReceived;
            serialPort.Close();
        }

        public void write(string message)
        {
            serialPort.Write(message);
            serialPort.Write("\r");
        }

        private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string s;
                while (serialPort.IsOpen && (s = serialPort.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, s);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        public event EventHandler<string> MessageReceived;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here, whilst I fixed my issue it wasn't the solution I wanted.

After reading [this](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) I got scared using SerialPort!

In the end I just had a single thread writing then calling `SerialPort.readLine()`. Far from ideal but I can get away with this as I know the MCU responds every time data is written.